# Prove that $m_k(I) \leq \frac{1}{\mu}(m_{k-1}(I_1) + m_{k-1}(I_3))$, where $m_k(I) =\inf_{x \in I}|f^{(k)}(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis

Function $f \in C^{n}(\left]-1; 1 \right[)$,  $\sup_{-1 < x <1}|f(x)| \leq 1$ and $m_k(I) =\inf_{x \in I}|f^{(k)}(x)|$, where *k* is *k-th* derivative.

Divide $I$ on three consecutive intervals $I_{1,2,3}$

Prove that: $$m_k(I) \leq \frac{1}{\mu}(m_{k-1}(I_1) + m_{k-1}(I_3))$$

where $\mu$ is length of $I_2$.

I think that here Lagrange's theorem can be used:

$$ f(b) - f(a) = f'(\xi)(b - a)$$

I assume that

$$ |f(b)| - |f(a)| = f'(\xi_1)(b - a)$$
So if use $i_{1,2,3}$ as $\inf_{x \in I_{1,2,3}}|f(x)|$ respectively,

we can cay

$$||f(i_3)| - ||f(i_2)|| = |f'(\xi_1)(i_3 - i_2)|$$
$$||f(i_2)| - ||f(i_1)|| = |f'(\xi_2)(i_2 - i_1)|$$

Since we interested in modulus and know that $i_3 > i_2$ and $i_2 > i_1$

$$||f(i_3)| - |f(i_2)|| = |f'(\xi_1)|(i_3 - i_2)$$
$$||f(i_2)| - |f(i_1)|| = |f'(\xi_2)|(i_2 - i_1)$$

By Lagrange's theorem  sequence, $m_1(I) \leq |f'(\xi_1)|, |f'(\xi_2)|$, since otherwise function couldn't cover distances beyond points $i$:

$$||f(i_3)| - |f(i_2)|| \geq m_1(I)(i_3 - i_2)$$
$$||f(i_2)| - |f(i_1)|| \geq m_1(I)(i_2 - i_1)$$

$$||f(i_3)| - |f(i_2)|| +  ||f(i_2)| - |f(i_1)|| \geq m_1 * \mu$$ since $\mu \le i_3 - i_1$

However, is it valid last step to take:

$$ (|f(i_3)| + |f(i_1)|)\frac{1}{\mu} \ge m_1$$

And general formula could be proved by inductions after this step.

But some steps I made seems doubtful to me.